# How to loop through each and every row, column and cells in a GridView and get its value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` which is databound, on button_click I want to read the `GridView` row by row each column and read the value of each cell in a row and update a table in database? I also know how to check if that cell contains null.

I am trying something like this and got stuck:

```
protected void SAVE_GRID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowscount = GridView2.Rows.Count;
    int columnscount = GridView2.Columns.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowscount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < columnscount; j++)
        {
            // I want to get data of each cell in a row
            // I want to read the corresponding header and store
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest would be using a `foreach`:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    // here you'll get all rows with RowType=DataRow
    // others like Header are omitted in a foreach
}
```

Edit: According to your edits, you are accessing the column incorrectly, you should start with 0:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < GridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        String header = GridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        String cellText = row.Cells[i].Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ArchanaB.R: Edited my answer. But this works only when you use BoundFields instead of TemplateFields. Then you need to use `FindControl` on the row to get a reference to your controls.

Comment: Yes I am using BoundFields. Well...but I want to read from 2nd column. SO can I give for(int i = 1; i < GridView2.Columns.Count, i++)..???

Comment: @ArchanaB.R: Yes of course you can start with 1 if you want. So it should work if you use `row.Cells[i].Text` as shown above.

Comment: @ArchanaB.R: You can use `int.Parse(cellText)` to parse a string to int.

Comment: I used : int cellText = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[i].Text); Is it right?

Comment: I would use `Convert.ToInt32` or `int.Parse` if you want an `int` instead of a `short`.

Comment: Where is the search value ?

Answer (score 6):

As it's said by "Tim Schmelter"  this is the best way :  just change  in it's code the seconde loop ( GridView2.Columns[i].Count by row.Cells.Count )   so it looks seem's that:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < GridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        String header = GridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        String cellText = row.Cells[i].Text;
    }
}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
            {
                if ( ! row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        String header = GridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                        String cellText = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[i].Value);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here Before Iterating for cell Values need to check for NewRow.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                String header = dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                //String cellText = row.Cells[i].Text;
                DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView1.Columns[i]; // column[1] selects the required column 
                column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells; // sets the AutoSizeMode of column defined in previous line
                int colWidth = column.Width; // store columns width after auto resize           
                colWidth += 50; // add 30 pixels to what 'colWidth' already is
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = colWidth; // set the columns width to the value stored in 'colWidth'
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please don't just post code - also explain how it solves the problem, if at all possible.