# How do I show null in data set instead of nothing while importing excel sheets

Tags: c#, .net, excel

```
    string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

    connExcel.Close();

    //Read Data from First Sheet
    connExcel.Open();
    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";

    oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
    oda.Fill(dt);
    connExcel.Close();
    GridView1.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

I am importing an Excel sheet but in place of null value I want the data set to show null instead of nothing.

Comment: You may need to explain this issue slightly better. Do you have an exception or an example of the output that is incorrect?

Comment: You want it to literally show `null`??

Comment: Added a language tag and tried to make it more readable. You may still want to add more detail about what you want to happen.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a method to the [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event and then iterate over each cell. If its content is `null` we set it to `"null"`:

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count, i++)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[i].Text))
        {
             e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "null";
        }
    }

}
```

If you want to do it outside the above event you need to iterate over each row first and then check the cells like demonstrated by Tim Schmelter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227742/how-to-loop-through-each-and-every-row-column-and-cells-in-a-gridview-and-get-i):

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count, i++)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrempty(row.Cells[i].Text))
        {
            row.Cells[i].Text = "null";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you should remove the ! before your condition, or else every rows but the null or empty ones will be set to "null".

Comment: Oh dear. That would be awkward. Thanks.