# How to add multiple rows in a stored procedure on a button click event ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

This is my stored procedure for purchasing toy after adding it to the cart

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PurchaseToys
    @ToyPurhcaseNo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
    @CartNo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @ToyNo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @MemberNo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,
    @TotalQuantity INTEGER,
    @TotalPrice INTEGER,
    @CreditCardNo BIGINT,
    @PurchaseDate DATETIME OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @ToyPurhcaseNo = NEWID()
    SET @PurchaseDate = GETDATE()

    INSERT INTO Toy_Purchase(Toy_Purchase_No, Cart_No, Toy_No, Member_No, Total_Quantity, Total_Price, Credit_Card_No, Purchase_Date)
    VALUES(@ToyPurhcaseNo, @CartNo, @ToyNo, @MemberNo, @TotalQuantity, @TotalPrice, @CreditCardNo, @PurchaseDate)

    UPDATE Toy
    SET Quantity = Quantity - Total_Price 
    FROM Toy, Toy_Purchase
    WHERE Toy.Toy_No = Toy_Purchase.Toy_No
END
```

This is my ADO.NET code in the CS file

```
 protected void Purchase_Click(object sender,EventArgs e )
 {
            string CartId = row.Cells[0].Text;
            string ToyId = row.Cells[1].Text;
            int TotalQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text);
            int TotalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Text);

            string CS1;
            CS1 = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Toy_WebForm; integrated security=SSPI";
            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(CS1);
            SqlTransaction Transaction = con1.BeginTransaction();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("PurchaseToys", con1, Transaction);
            cmd1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CartNo", CartId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToyNo", ToyId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberNo", MemberId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalQuantity", TotalQuantity);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPrice", TotalPrice);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreditCardNo", TextBox2.Text);

            con1.Open();
            SqlParameter OutputParameter1 = new SqlParameter();
            OutputParameter1.ParameterName = "@CartNo";
            OutputParameter1.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier;
            OutputParameter1.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add(OutputParameter1);

            SqlParameter OutputParameter2 = new SqlParameter();
            OutputParameter2.ParameterName = "@PurchaseDate";
            OutputParameter2.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime;
            OutputParameter2.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add(OutputParameter2);

            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.Transaction.Commit();

            con1.Close();

            MessageBox("You have successfully purchased");
}

public void MessageBox(string message)
{
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "MessageBox", "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + message + "')</script>");
}
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is that in the shopping cart web page, if I have 2 separate carts for 2 different toys , the stored procedure "PurchaseToys" should insert 2 rows in the table on Purchase button click event. If I have 4 separate carts for 4 different toys , the stored procedure "PurchaseToys" should insert 4 rows in the table on Purchase button click event. If I have single cart for a single toy, the stored procedure "PurchaseToys" should insert single row in the table on Purchase button click event.

So my question is how do I insert multiple rows in the table on Purchase button click event?

If there is error in my code syntax, then kindly show the appropriate syntax for what I want to achieve.

Thanks.

Comment: what you do mean by **if I have 2 separate carts for 2 different toys** ? there are multiple Gridview?

Comment: Yes you are right, there are multiple rows in the gridview in the webpage.

Comment: why dont you loop through your Gridview? [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227742/how-to-loop-through-each-and-every-row-column-and-cells-in-a-gridview-and-get-i)

Comment: I'm thinking of putting the Gridview row and the stored procedure in a foreach loop. Do you think this is the ideal solution?

Comment: This is  classic case to use a table valued parameter. However, Your are going about it in a strange way. It's a classic orders and orderDetails tables, but it seems in your case you have a different order for each product.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged