# Execute loop in stored procedure to insert the data in SQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, gridview

How to execute a loop in a stored procedure to insert the data in a SQL query?

For demo, I have a gridview in that there is 10 rows of data now that 10 rows of data I want to insert into a table through a stored procedure.

So, as per the logic to insert that 10 rows of data I want to use the loop. Now, the problem that only that how can I use loop of that gridview in the stored procedure.

[image]

The screenshot show there are columns:

```
srno, accountname, cramount, dramount, tdsamt, sgstamt, cgstamt, igstamt
```

Now, how I will insert this multiple data(as per in image shown) in tmptable through a stored procedure?

Please help me to solve this issues.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post up some sample data, before, and what you want inserted? You may not need to use a loop.

Comment: @Leonidas199x I updated the image. Please review it. And I think so for insert the gridview data loop only can use. Is there any other idea then please share it.

Comment: What language is your gridview in?   You should tag that language as that is where you will need to write your loop.

Comment: I am doing in asp.net with c#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through each and every row, column and cells in a GridView and get its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227742/how-to-loop-through-each-and-every-row-column-and-cells-in-a-gridview-and-get-i)

Comment: @TabAlleman but i am asking in sqlserver not any form so for thats why you dont want to know the language. how dai you to do the lower rate. first read question properly then come.

Comment: @TabAlleman are you mad. I am asking in sql query not any form. read topic as well as question.

Comment: You can't loop a C# gridview in SQL.

Comment: thats why I never tag a language c# in a question. understand what I am telling you.

Answer (score 2):

As per your need, you can go with bulk insert using XML instead of loop. XML bulk insertion is faster then loop.

All you need to pass your data in XML format to stored procedure. And, Insert that data from XML format, to your table.

You can follow given link, Or you can do google. You will easily get the Solution on google.

1.How to Pass data into XML format;
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b926a6/insert-multiple-bulk-data-row-in-database-using-xml-in-asp-n/

2. How to insert data into table from XML format
   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/bulk-insert-into-sql-database-using-xml-file1